# Signalr: Websockets connection issue

Tags: websocket, connection, signalr, signalr-hub

Our application uses SignalR and we have enabled the websockets in our applicaiton. Sometimes we are getting the below error in browser console window and during the same time the auto update is not working. After the relaunch it is started working.

**Firefox:**
"The connection to ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=%2F54BwG4ui3MbJPK2t8DfS9AklLCtAEDQ1sHeAsZ6e3h2LVT0WYbbgGvCI2AlnsJf0AqY4AzMtp6FS0xl07td8kKFYhAmIEL4GjLCXP%2Bhlfy3k226j%2B4fXHVB8Vvblewc&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22pushdatahub%22%7D%5D&tid=7 was interrupted while the page was loading."

**Chrome:**
jquery.signalR-1.0.0.min.js:10  WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Please refer below setup done on the server.

- .Net framework 4.6.1 in the server.
- websockets enabled in IIS/Application
- httpruntime set in web.config
- Server uses SignalR Hub

Sample client code:

```
$scope.isHubConnectionFailed = false;
$scope.connection = $.hubConnection(AppURL);
$scope.HubProxy = $scope.connection.createHubProxy(App.chatHub);

$scope.connection.start()
    .done(function () {
        $scope.isHubConnectionFailed = false;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $scope.isHubConnectionFailed = true;
    });

var tryingToReconnect = false;

$scope.connection.reconnecting(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = true;
});

$scope.connection.reconnected(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = false;
    $scope.isHubConnectionFailed = false;
});

$scope.connection.disconnected(function() {
    if (tryingToReconnect) {
        $scope.isHubConnectionFailed = true;
    }
});
```

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the browser your using.

Supported Platforms: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

There is an issue I found with signalr and azure, I am not sure if that is your situation but it might help to debug the issue. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2780

Comment: We are using the latest browser version!

Comment: Not sure if you are using azure or not, but I found an issue with the socket closing before the connection is completed. I will add it to my answer